# find_package of cmake do not work when I combine it with add_subdirectory

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

Migrating qmake to cmake

Project structure

```
project
--CMakeLists.txt
  --configurations
    --CMakeLists.txt
    --other files
```

project/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
     
project(build_all_libs)
    
add_subdirectory(configurations)
```

project/configurations/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
     
project(configurations)
     
set(3RDLIBS_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../3rdLibs)
set(OPENCV_PREFIX_PATH ${3RDLIBS_PATH}/opencv/opencv_4_5_0/opencv/build)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${OPENCV_PREFIX_PATH};${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH};")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

file(GLOB UTILS_SRC
    "*.hpp"
    "*.cpp"    
)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/..)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${UTILS_SRC})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

I can compile the configurations if I open the project/configurations/CMakeLists.txt directly, but I cannot find the opencv package if I try to build it by project/CMakeLists.txt, it give me error messages

```
CMake Error at configurations/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:
    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake
  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

How could I fix this? Thanks

Comment: When you build the root project, the variable [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) to **its source directory** even if you use this variable in `configuration/CMakeLists.txt`. If inside `configuration/CMakeLists.txt` you want to refer to `configuration/` directory, then use variable [CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html) instead.

Comment: Note: you are making this vastly overcomplicated. I suggest you read some guide on modern CMake, such as [this one](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/).